# Query on a field value - returns Global name not defined

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Im tryin to write a query to filter/exclude some objects from a list, but I get a error.

My models:

```
class Benefit(TimeStampedModel):
    DEAL = 'D'
    NODEAL = 'N'

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (NODEAL, 'Does not need any signed deal'),
        (DEAL, 'Needs a signed deal'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    benefit_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=DEAL)    



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    benefits = models.ManyToManyField(Benefit, verbose_name="Used benefits", blank=True, null=True, related_name="used_benefit")
```

My view:

```
class ProfilePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "profile/frontpage.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(ProfileFrontpage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['unused_benefits'] = Benefit.objects.filter(used_benefit__isnull=True).exclude(benefit_type=='N')
            context['nodeal_benefits'] = Benefit.objects.filter(benefit_type=='N')
            return context
```

But it is not working. I get this error: `global name 'benefit_type' is not defined`

I not sure why I get that error? I did not think I needed to make a variable of a model field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In filter queries you don't need `==` for comparison.

Update your view code as

```
context['unused_benefits'] = Benefit.objects.filter(used_benefit__isnull=True).exclude((benefit_type = 'N')
context['nodeal_benefits'] = Benefit.objects.filter(benefit_type = 'N')
# ---------------------------------------------------------------^ single =
```